# Contained draggable div with random positioning has 'no' bottom limits

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, web

Here is where I am for the moment : http://jsfiddle.net/___Vikus___/tk0mn4je/

```
$(function () {
    $(".col1").each(
    function (intIndex) {
        var l = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".col1").width());
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".col1").height());
        $(this).css("left", l);
        $(this).css("top", r);
    });
    $(".col1").draggable({
        containment: "#wraper",
        scroll: false,
        stack: ".col1"
    });
});
```

The script for random positioning works fine but the draggable propriety has no bottom containment. So how could I limit my random positioning inside a div ? Or, what could I do to create a real bottom limit ?

Comment: It is contained within the wrapper however it is contained by the very top of the draggable div

Comment: How could it be contained by both top and bottom ?

Comment: sorry so it is contained by the wrapper however it is based off the top edge of your draggable div. If you know the exact size of your wrapper then you can set containment: to ([x1,y1,x2,y2]) on the y1 and y2 do the height of your wrapper minus the height of your draggable div

Comment: The size of my wrapper can only be in pixel right ? Thanks for the answer 'cause I'll maybe do it like that, but  it's for blog and I don't know yet how many articles I'll have…

Comment: Yes if your site is responsive it will be alot harder. I found a site with a working example where the bottom is contained and they use: $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    cursor: 'move',
    snap: '#content'
  } );

See here for example http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/draggable-options.html

Comment: A big thank you for this documentation/tutorial ! Sorry for wasting your time